# mysql error #1064 when trying to limit results where count() not 0

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have query

```
SELECT helpc.cid, COUNT(help.cid) AS children_count FROM air_help_category AS helpc LEFT JOIN air_help AS help ON helpc.cid = help.cid GROUP BY cid WHERE hildren_count > 0
```

but I get

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE children_count > 0 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Checked the coresponding error code, but still could not fix this.

All I'm trying to achieve is to get those ids, who have at least one children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `WHERE` clause should go before `GROUP BY`. Also, you can't use aggregate field values for `WHERE` - use `HAVING` instead, like this:

```
SELECT helpc.cid, COUNT(help.cid) AS children_count 
FROM air_help_category AS helpc LEFT JOIN air_help AS help ON helpc.cid = help.cid 
GROUP BY cid 
HAVING COUNT(help.cid) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. I just dont know so in depth mysql

Answer (score 2):

Put the 'where' before the 'group by'

Comment: That worked but I got `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: It may be confused because you have two tables with 'cid' columns. Try specifying which table you want to group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT helpc.cid, COUNT(help.cid) AS children_count
FROM air_help_category AS helpc LEFT JOIN air_help AS help
ON (helpc.cid = help.cid) WHERE children_count &lt; 0 GROUP BY cid
```

Comment: Hey there, I've come across a few of your posts today through `/review`. FYI, on SO you can (and should) format your code by indenting it four spaces instead of using HTML `<pre>` and `<code>` blocks. You can also select an entire code block and press `Ctrl` + `K` to do all the indenting at once. Keep up the good work!